# VSCode Jupyter Notebook Error not showing up

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to use VSCode's Jupyter notebook plugin on my remote linux server, however, I'm getting an issue where errors are not being raised. As you can see in the screenshot, I used a try catch to print the error, however, nothing happens when I raise it and I'm not sure why. [Try catch with no error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WqMn.png)

This of course holds for when I do more advanced blocks of code, and it makes it quite annoying to debug when the errors aren't raised and I have to use a try catch everywhere to see what is going on.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does it work locally?

Comment: That picture looks like a very old version of the Jupyter extension. Can you update to the newest version?